# Why while loop is working randomly?

Tags: r, function, while-loop

I am confused while my while loop is working randomly?

```
how.many<-function(fruit, number){
  string<-paste("How many",fruit,"?",sep=" ")
  fruit_number<-readline(string)
  print("fruit number")
  print(fruit_number)
  print("number")
  print(number)
  while(fruit_number > number){
    print("inside while")
    print("fruit number")
    print(fruit_number)
    print("number")
    print(number)
    print("ERROR: too many for the budget")
    string<-paste("How many",fruit,"?",sep=" ")
    fruit_number<-readline(string)
  }
  return(as.numeric(fruit_number))
}
```

Here's when I call this function:

```
> source("fruit.R")
> how.many("apple",6)
How many apple ?3
[1] "fruit number"
[1] "3"
[1] "number"
[1] 6
[1] 3
> how.many("apple",10)
How many apple ?9
[1] "fruit number"
[1] "9"
[1] "number"
[1] 10
[1] "inside while"
[1] "fruit number"
[1] "9"
[1] "number"
[1] 10
[1] "ERROR: too many for the budget"
How many apple ?7
[1] "inside while"
[1] "fruit number"
[1] "7"
[1] "number"
[1] 10
[1] "ERROR: too many for the budget"
How many apple ?2
[1] "inside while"
[1] "fruit number"
[1] "2"
[1] "number"
[1] 10
[1] "ERROR: too many for the budget"
How many apple ?1
[1] 1
```

Any hint?

Comment: `fruit_number` is a character and you try and use it as a numeric. that causes a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `fruit_number` to a number, not a string.

e.g.

```
fruit_number <- as.numeric(readline(string))
```

or

```
fruit_number <- as.integer(readline(string))
```

Otherwise the numbers are compared as strings, and "9" is greater than "10" in the string sense.